# How to set wifi max connection tries?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, connection

I have a wifi network configured within networkmanager. Unfortunately I cannot use this as long as I sit on my workplace as there is the signal is very low. But when I go over to other workplaces of colleagues it will nearly work. The SSID, however, is visible at my workplace and ubuntu tries to connect again and again. I won't disable Wifi since, I will forget to reenable when I move to other places. Neither I want to delete the network as I will use it on other places at work. So how do I overcome this annoying connection failure dialogs for that network? Is there a maximum number of connection tries I could decrease? I use 11.10.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable auto connect in network manager. It will not try to connect by itself.

Comment: Great, as it is connection specific :D.